# Mockito: How to verify a mock is the last mock invoked?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I know about Mockito.InOrder (http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/InOrder.html)

Altough it has been good use for me to test a mock is invoked before any other mock in a method, I can't find a way to use it in order to check if a specific mock is the last invoked.

In my case, I'm testing a mediator which calls several interfaces. In a finally statement, a lock is unlocked.

I want my unit test to specifically test that whether there is an exception or not, the lock is released no matter what, and of course after any other operation, no matter how many were executed.

I have the list of mocks that are involved but I can't figure out how to tell Mockito :

- Hey ! InOrder.verify(aMockWhichIsNotTheLast, atLeast(0)).anyMethod()
- Then InOrder.verify(wantedMock).unlock(), so this way I know my mock was the last mock invoked among all my mocks.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try and `verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock1, mock2, etc)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would mean I would have to verify every mock interaction before doing this line otherwise that would fail saying there were interactions for most mocks. As I said, I'd like to have that test to be independant and not linked to the number of interfaces called in the mediator (i.e the number of mocks).

Comment: Easy peasy ;) Let me show you what I mean in an answer...

Comment: See my answer. I'm sure you can find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class such as this

```
public final class Mocks
{
    private final List<Object> mocks = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T> T register(final T mock)
    {
        mocks.add(Objects.requireNonNull(mock));
        return mock;
    }

    public InOrder inOrder()
    {
        return Mockito.inOrder(mocks.toArray());
    }

    public void verifyNoMoreInteractions()
    {
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mocks.toArray());
    }
}
```

You can then use your class as such:

```
final Mocks mocks = new Mocks();

final Whatever mock1 = mocks.register(mock(Whatever.class));
final Whatever2 mock2 = mocks.register(mock(Whatever2.class));

final InOrder inOrder = mocks.inOrder();

// verify, verify, verify

mocks.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, let met know. But all I see is a wrapper around mockito methods. How does that allow me to check a mock has been called last without verifying every other mock call ?

Comment: Example: Mock1, Mock2, Mock3. 

The tested method does mock1.operation1, mock2.operation2, mock3.operation3.

In my case, there are so much mocks, I have the list of mocks, but I only want to check mock3 is called last. Without verifying mock1 and mock2 interactions.

Comment: This aspect was not clear at all from your question... Now I understand the problem at last. Don't you think there is a little problem with your test to begin with? You should not have that many mocks...

Comment: Good point, I was not clear enough. Sorry about that. 

To answer your question, I would be concerned about the amount of mocks if the tested class wasn't a mediator. But in that case, that's normal that there are many interfaces. 

The only reason I don't want to write the dozens of Verify before doing the last "inOrder.verify" is that I prefer to have many small unit tests, which are stricly testing a particular thing, instead of bigger ones with tons of verifications we don't care about just for the sake of testing a finally.

I'll do a less restrictive test then, thanks for your time.